# trying to make a code that sends a confirm email

Tags: php

trying to make a code that will send a confirmation email to my members,
when they join up it will send it directly to there emails,
only to new members, i have tried couple different factors but it wont send out anything.
any suggestions?

```
$EMAIL=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"EMAIL");
    $to = $EMAIL;
    $subject = "Florida Fields To Forks - Order Confirmation";
    $message = "Thank for your order! You can check your order here: http://www.floridafieldstoforks.com/order.php?orderid=$orderid";
    $from = "floridafieldstoforks@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: Check the spam folder.  Do you see the email there?  Check the error log.  Is there anything related to this script?  Log the `$to` to make sure you're getting an email address from the database (is `$resultt` a typo?).

Comment: well the thing is that i am confused with, is the code works on another page on my website for orders, but on the join page it wont grab the member id or the email automatically to send an email, i have it already set to submit a copy to my email to who joins but how would i be able to send them a copy when they join as well? can i join the codes?

Comment: Use `print_r($EMAIL)`, see  if it is an address yet, not a mysql result resource or empty value. Also, PHPMailer/SwiftMailer are more contemporary than mail().

Comment: i use this code to send me a email with the members info can i add anything to this code to send the member an email as well?

Comment: $to = "floridafieldstoforks@gmail.com"; 
  $subject = "New Membership Sign Up"; 
  $message =     "First Name:" . $_POST['one'] . "\n" .
                 "Last Name:" . $_POST['two'] . "\n" .
                 "Email:" . $_POST['three'] . "\n" .
                 "Password:" . $_POST['four'] . "\n" .
                 "Phone:" . $_POST['five'] . "\n" .
                 "Address 1:" . $_POST['six'] . "\n" .
                 "Address 2:" . $_POST['seven'] . "\n" .
                 "Pick Up City:" . $_POST['eight'] . "\n" .
                 "State:" . $_POST['nine'];
  mail($to, $subject, $message);

Comment: @RyanBacchus: Don't post code in the comments.  Go back and edit your original post.

Answer (score 0):

check the value of the var $to because the send can be fail if you don't have the correct format of the email address, if the addresses are more than one check that they be separated by comma.

I tested you code and it worked perfect in my server.

An other posibility is that you are sending the email from gmail.com domain.
Gmail can block yor ip because your ip is not authorized to send mails of that domain.

test your code changing the domain of the from address

Comment: can i add a $from ="email" and message with the code sending me an email? and that will send the user that just joined an email?

Comment: so will i add $from="email" , then $message="" ? or what would i input in the code to make that work?

Comment: for testing var $from='email'; and var $to='floridafieldstoforks@gmail.com'; leave the rest of the code as it is.
the code will send an email to floridafieldstoforks@gmail.com.

Comment: well yea that part works but i am trying to send the new member a email, stating welcome etc,

Comment: mmm, I think the problem is in the format of the receiver address

Answer (score 0):

If the order id is "1001".  Save the order id in DB with current User id (User id of current placed order ) .

In mail send Order id **http://www.floridafieldstoforks.com/order.php?orderid=1001**

In order.php file write the query as.

```
$query= "Select user_id from TABLE where order_id='1001'";
mysql_query($query);
```

And set the session user_id from the query result.